# Leetcode 126: Word Ladder 2 in Python code optimization

Tags: optimization, python-3.6, breadth-first-search

I have the solution for the Word Ladder 2 (Leetcode problem 126: [Word Ladder 2](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder-ii/) ) in Python 3.6, and I notice that one of the very last testcases times out for me on the platform. Funnily, the test passes when run on PyCharm or as an individual test case on the site, but it takes about 5 seconds for it to complete. My solution uses BFS with some optimizations, but can someone tell me if there is a way to make it faster. Thank you! (P.S: Apologies for the additional test cases included in the commented out section!)

```
import math
import queue
from typing import List


class WordLadder2(object):

    @staticmethod
    def is_one_hop_away(s1: str, s2: str) -> int:
        """
        Uses the distance between strings to return True if string s2 is one character away from s1
        :param s1: Base string
        :param s2: Comparison string
        :return: True if it the difference between the strings is one character
        """
        matrix = [[0] * (len(s1) + 1) for i in range(len(s1) + 1)]
        for r, row in enumerate(matrix):
            for c, entry in enumerate(row):
                if not r:
                    matrix[r][c] = c
                elif not c:
                    matrix[r][c] = r
                else:
                    if s1[r - 1] == s2[c - 1]:
                        matrix[r][c] = matrix[r - 1][c - 1]
                    else:
                        matrix[r][c] = 1 + min(matrix[r - 1][c - 1], matrix[r - 1][c], matrix[r][c - 1])

        if matrix[-1][-1] == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_next_words(self, s1: str, wordList: List[str]) -> List[str]:
        """
        For a given string in the list, return a set of strings that are one hop away
        :param s1: String whose neighbors one hop away are needed
        :param wordList: Array of words to choose from
        :return: List of words that are one character away from given string s1
        """
        words = []
        for word in wordList:
            if self.is_one_hop_away(s1, word):
                words.append(word)
        return words

    def find_ladders(self, beginWord: str, endWord: str, wordList: List[str]) -> List[List[str]]:
        """
        Main method to determine shortest paths between a beginning word and an ending word, in a given list of words
        :param beginWord: Word to begin the ladder
        :param endWord: Word to end the ladder
        :param wordList: List of words to choose from
        :return: List of list of word ladders, if they are found. Empty list, if endWord not in wordList or path not
        found from beginWord to endWord
        """

        q = queue.Queue()
        paths = list()
        current = [beginWord]
        q.put((beginWord, current))
        # Set to track words we have already processed
        visited = set()
        # Dictionary to keep track of the shortest path lengths to each word from beginWord
        shortest_paths = {beginWord: 1}
        min_length = math.inf

        # Use BFS to find the shortest path in the graph
        while q.qsize():
            word, path = q.get()
            # If endWord is found, add the current path to the list of paths and compute minimum path
            # length found so far
            if word == endWord:
                paths.append(path)
                min_length = min(min_length, len(path))
                continue

            for hop in self.get_next_words(word, wordList):
                # If the hop is already processed or in the queue for processing, skip
                if hop in visited or hop in q.queue:
                    continue
                # If the shortest path to the hop has not been determined or the current path length is lesser
                # than or equal to the known shortest path to the hop, add it to the queue and update the shortest
                # path to the hop.
                if (hop not in shortest_paths) or (hop in shortest_paths and len(path + [hop]) <= shortest_paths[hop]):
                    q.put((hop, path + [hop]))
                    shortest_paths[hop] = len(path + [hop])
            visited.add(word)

        return [s for s in paths if len(s) == min_length]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # beginword = 'qa'
    # endword = 'sq'
    # wordlist = ["si","go","se","cm","so","ph","mt","db","mb","sb","kr","ln","tm","le","av","sm","ar","ci","ca","br","ti","ba","to","ra","fa","yo","ow","sn","ya","cr","po","fe","ho","ma","re","or","rn","au","ur","rh","sr","tc","lt","lo","as","fr","nb","yb","if","pb","ge","th","pm","rb","sh","co","ga","li","ha","hz","no","bi","di","hi","qa","pi","os","uh","wm","an","me","mo","na","la","st","er","sc","ne","mn","mi","am","ex","pt","io","be","fm","ta","tb","ni","mr","pa","he","lr","sq","ye"]
    # beginword = 'hit'
    # endword = 'cog'
    # wordlist = ['hot', 'dot', 'dog', 'lot', 'log', 'cog']
    # beginword = 'red'
    # endword = 'tax'
    # wordlist = ['ted', 'tex', 'red', 'tax', 'tad', 'den', 'rex', 'pee']
    beginword = 'cet'
    endword = 'ism'
    wordlist = ["kid","tag","pup","ail","tun","woo","erg","luz","brr","gay","sip","kay","per","val","mes","ohs","now","boa","cet","pal","bar","die","war","hay","eco","pub","lob","rue","fry","lit","rex","jan","cot","bid","ali","pay","col","gum","ger","row","won","dan","rum","fad","tut","sag","yip","sui","ark","has","zip","fez","own","ump","dis","ads","max","jaw","out","btu","ana","gap","cry","led","abe","box","ore","pig","fie","toy","fat","cal","lie","noh","sew","ono","tam","flu","mgm","ply","awe","pry","tit","tie","yet","too","tax","jim","san","pan","map","ski","ova","wed","non","wac","nut","why","bye","lye","oct","old","fin","feb","chi","sap","owl","log","tod","dot","bow","fob","for","joe","ivy","fan","age","fax","hip","jib","mel","hus","sob","ifs","tab","ara","dab","jag","jar","arm","lot","tom","sax","tex","yum","pei","wen","wry","ire","irk","far","mew","wit","doe","gas","rte","ian","pot","ask","wag","hag","amy","nag","ron","soy","gin","don","tug","fay","vic","boo","nam","ave","buy","sop","but","orb","fen","paw","his","sub","bob","yea","oft","inn","rod","yam","pew","web","hod","hun","gyp","wei","wis","rob","gad","pie","mon","dog","bib","rub","ere","dig","era","cat","fox","bee","mod","day","apr","vie","nev","jam","pam","new","aye","ani","and","ibm","yap","can","pyx","tar","kin","fog","hum","pip","cup","dye","lyx","jog","nun","par","wan","fey","bus","oak","bad","ats","set","qom","vat","eat","pus","rev","axe","ion","six","ila","lao","mom","mas","pro","few","opt","poe","art","ash","oar","cap","lop","may","shy","rid","bat","sum","rim","fee","bmw","sky","maj","hue","thy","ava","rap","den","fla","auk","cox","ibo","hey","saw","vim","sec","ltd","you","its","tat","dew","eva","tog","ram","let","see","zit","maw","nix","ate","gig","rep","owe","ind","hog","eve","sam","zoo","any","dow","cod","bed","vet","ham","sis","hex","via","fir","nod","mao","aug","mum","hoe","bah","hal","keg","hew","zed","tow","gog","ass","dem","who","bet","gos","son","ear","spy","kit","boy","due","sen","oaf","mix","hep","fur","ada","bin","nil","mia","ewe","hit","fix","sad","rib","eye","hop","haw","wax","mid","tad","ken","wad","rye","pap","bog","gut","ito","woe","our","ado","sin","mad","ray","hon","roy","dip","hen","iva","lug","asp","hui","yak","bay","poi","yep","bun","try","lad","elm","nat","wyo","gym","dug","toe","dee","wig","sly","rip","geo","cog","pas","zen","odd","nan","lay","pod","fit","hem","joy","bum","rio","yon","dec","leg","put","sue","dim","pet","yaw","nub","bit","bur","sid","sun","oil","red","doc","moe","caw","eel","dix","cub","end","gem","off","yew","hug","pop","tub","sgt","lid","pun","ton","sol","din","yup","jab","pea","bug","gag","mil","jig","hub","low","did","tin","get","gte","sox","lei","mig","fig","lon","use","ban","flo","nov","jut","bag","mir","sty","lap","two","ins","con","ant","net","tux","ode","stu","mug","cad","nap","gun","fop","tot","sow","sal","sic","ted","wot","del","imp","cob","way","ann","tan","mci","job","wet","ism","err","him","all","pad","hah","hie","aim"]
    wl = WordLadder2()
    # beginword = 'hot'
    # endword = 'dog'
    # wordlist = ['hot', 'dog', 'dot']
    print(wl.find_ladders(beginword, endword, wordlist))
```

Answer (score 1):

The part that slows down your solution is `is_one_hop_away`, which is a costly function. This is called repeatedly during the actual BFS. Instead you should aim to first create a graph structure -- an adjacency list -- so that complexity of *calculating* which words are neighbors is dealt with before actually peforming the BFS search.

Here is one way to do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Solution:
    def findLadders(self, beginWord: str, endWord: str, wordList: List[str]) -> List[List[str]]:
        
        def createAdjacencyList(wordList):
            adj = defaultdict(set)
            d = defaultdict(set)
            for word in wordList:
                for i in range(len(word)):
                    derived = word[:i] + "*" + word[i+1:]
                    for neighbor in d[derived]:
                        adj[word].add(neighbor)
                        adj[neighbor].add(word)
                    d[derived].add(word)
            return adj
        
        def edgesOnShortestPaths(adj, beginWord, endWord):
            frontier = [beginWord]
            edges = defaultdict(list)
            edges[beginWord] = []
            while endWord not in frontier:
                nextfrontier = set(neighbor
                    for word in frontier
                    for neighbor in adj[word]
                    if neighbor not in edges
                )
                if not nextfrontier:  # endNode is not reachable
                    return
                for word in frontier:
                    for neighbor in adj[word]:
                        if neighbor in nextfrontier:
                            edges[neighbor].append(word)
                frontier = nextfrontier
            return edges
        
        def generatePaths(edges, word):
            if not edges[word]:
                yield [word]
            else:
                for neighbor in edges[word]:
                    for path in generatePaths(edges, neighbor):
                        yield path + [word]
            

        if endWord not in wordList:  # shortcut exit
            return []
        adj = createAdjacencyList([beginWord] + wordList)
        edges = edgesOnShortestPaths(adj, beginWord, endWord)
        if not edges:  # endNode is not reachable
            return []
        return list(generatePaths(edges, endWord))
```